# Django admin: how do I filter a ForeignKeyField widget based on the object's (not request.user's) data?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.3

I have `Chart` and Module models (see code below). Each chart belongs to a module (via a `ForeignKey`). A chart may have another chart as its `parent` (another `ForeignKey`). What I would like in the admin is that the dropdown for `parent` on a particular chart *only includes charts in the same module*.

I'm looking for a Python solution, not AJAX. That means that on creating a new chart the dropdown will have to be empty (without a model instance there's no module selected) and that changing the module in the admin won't update the `parent` options to match until the model is saved. I'm ok with that.

There are plenty of similar-sounding questions (and answers) that turn out to filter the options according to the *user*; `ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey` gets the request as an argument so you can use `request.user`, but it doesn't get given a model instance to play with. (I'm using Django 1.3.)

My models (highly simplified of course):

```
class Module(models.Model):
    pass

class Chart(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Chart, blank=True, null=True)

class ChartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        # I would like to do this, but have no "instance":
        kwargs['queryset'] = Chart.objects.filter(module=instance.module)
        return super(ChartAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Chart, ChartAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just override the `ModelForm` being used:

```
class ChartAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChartAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.module_id:
            self.fields['parent'].queryset = self.fields['parent'].queryset.filter(module=self.instance.module)

class ChartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ChartAdminForm
    ...
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I've added an edit (in queue) to make it also safe for instance creation (when self.instance.module raises a DoesNotExist).

Answer (score 2):

From what i've seen in the source code, kwargs should contain only the widget (not helping !).

One possible hack, would be to override the get_form() modeladmin method, just to set request.current_object. Then, you could use request.current_object in formfield_callback:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    request.current_object = obj
    return super(ChartAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    instance = request.current_object

    kwargs['queryset'] = Chart.objects.filter(module=instance.module)
    return super(ChartAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs)
```